# Phase angle in a series RC circuit

Tags: capacitor, circuit-analysis, resistors, ac, phase

I have a simple question from an electronics textbook (Electronics Fundamentals, Pearson, 8th Ed., p510 Q 37):

10V 10 Hz AC supply, 4.7K resistor and 10uF capacitor in series, with Vout measured over the capacitor.

What is the output voltage and phase angle?

I think:

Xc = 1592 Ohms

Z = 4700 - 1592i

Vout = 10 * -1592i / (4700 - 1592i) = 1.03 - 3.04i = 3.2V @ -71.3 degrees

The answer given is 3.2V @ 18.7 degrees.

How come the answer is off by 90 degrees?

Comment: They probably calculated `atan(-1592/4700)`, but you calculated correctly, if it's an RC lowpass (by your Xc I presume 10Hz, right?).

Comment: Yes, Vout is measured across the capacitor so it's an RC low-pass filter.

Comment: Then you got this. ;-)

Comment: Thanks! -yes, I forgot to mention 10Hz.